# Using an addEventListener to update/increment a counter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Simple question - I don't quite understand why my counter variable is not updating when I click the submit button (input type submit) based on the click using an eventlistener. The rest of the code is fine, I just want to know why my "counter++" doesn't add 1 to the counter value when I click the button.

```
let counter = 0;
submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counter++;
    -----FEEL FREE TO IGNORE THE CODE BELOW THIS----
    let captureInput = document.getElementById('primaryGuess');
    storeGuess(captureInput.value);
    const newLi = document.createElement("LI");
    const LiContent = document.createTextNode(captureInput.value);
    newLi.appendChild(LiContent);
    listOfPriorGuesses.appendChild(newLi);
    arrayOfGuesses.forEach((currNum) => {
        if (parseInt(currNum) === randomNumber) {
            gameTitle.innerText = "YOU WIN!!!"
            gameTitle.style.color = "green"
            captureInput.value = "Click Play Again!"
        } else if(parseInt(currNum) < randomNumber) {
            captureInput.value = "Guess Higher!"
        } else if(parseInt(currNum) > randomNumber) {
            captureInput.value = "Guess Lower!"
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Please see the minimal code below. If you are using `input type='button'` inside a form you need to use `e.preventDefault()` else the form will be submitted. May be you are having that scenario. You can also use `type='button'` in that case you dont need `e.preventDefault();`

```js
let counter = 0;
let submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

let inputSubmitButton = document.getElementById('inputSubmit');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});


inputSubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
```

```html
<button id='submitButton'> Button </button>


<form>
  <input id='inputSubmit' type="submit" value="Submit button" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am actually using input type = submit. Do I have to change it to type button for this to work?

Comment: If you change it to `type="button"` then you don't need the call to `preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Bixar either `type = submit` with `e.preventDefault()` or type = button` then no need of `e.preventDefault()`  - both will work